# VB.Net Print Preview Icon Change

Tags: vb.net, printing, preview

I am back again with another question that I could not find answer to in the search engines;
I am trying to change the Print Preview Icon to be same as the Main form (Form1) icon;

I tried the following without success;
I appreciate the help.

```
     PrintPreviewDialog1.ShowIcon = My.Resources.Icon
     PrintPreviewDialog1.Icon = Me.Icon
     PrintPreviewDialog1.Icon = Form1.Icon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what problems or errors that you are getting. Creating a small test application where I am dynamically creating the `PrintPreviewDialog` and assigning the Form's Icon to it before showing it works for me.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim printPreviewDialog1 As New PrintPreviewDialog
    printPreviewDialog1.Icon = Icon
    printPreviewDialog1.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Comment: WOW; Mark; I feel so stupid that I did not try this option; and You are wonderful :-)   Much appreciate the help....

Comment: Glad I was able to be of help, though it is very close to what you already had tried.